# nagios: how to create stacked chart/graphs?

Tags: graph, charts, monitoring, nagios

Some nagios services (as memory usage) are shown by means of graphs but a graph per item (free, used, buffer, cache,...) is created. Instead, I want to have a stacked graph (similar to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aF%C3%B6rs%C3%A4ljningsstatistik_f%C3%B6r_blanddrycker.png))

Is that possible?

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is going to depend on which graphing add-on for Nagios you are using to process the perfdata and generate the graphs.

For example, if you are using pnp4nagios, you can do stacked graphs.  You need to create a custom template in your pnp4nagios/share/templates dir called xxx.php where xxx is the name of the checkcommand.  This is a php script containing all the RRD commands to generate the graph; this can be rather complex so you need to know PHP and read the RRDTool documentation.

Comment: Thanks, Steve. I'm going to check the graphing add-on in my Nagios server.